# Splitting the content of file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given comma separated names of president with some details like this :

```
James Earl Carter, Jr., 1977-1981, Democrat
Ronald Wilson Reagan, 1981-1989, Republican
George Herbert Walker Bush, 1989-1993, Republican
```

Now I want three lists like this :

```
Name = ['Carter' , 'Reagan' , 'Bush']

StartYears = [1977,1981,1989]

EndYears = [1981,1989,1993]

Party = ['Democrat','Republican','Republican']
```

But some problems am facing :

```
James Earl Carter, Jr. contains comma already so splitting is not working properly.
```

How to do it ? Please help.

Comment: Where are these listing coming from?

Comment: You will need to use a regular expression to parse those lines

Comment: for `years` and `party` contains no commas, you can just use `.split`

Comment: Little OT, but '_' in variables instead of camel-case is more pythonic. e.g. use 'start_years' instead of 'StartYears'.

Answer (score 4):

From your dataset it looks like only the name can have `,` in them, others would not, so you can use `rsplit` function which splits from the back, and give it the paramter `','` and `2` , which means split from back using comma and stop at 2 splits.

Example -

```
s = "James Earl Carter, Jr., 1977-1981, Democrat".rsplit(',',2)
print(s)
>> ['James Earl Carter, Jr.', ' 1977-1981', ' Democrat']
```

Also, if for `name` list, the condition is to pick the last name in the list if there are no `,` or if there are comma, pick the last name just before first comma. A simple solution would be to split the name list again using ',' , this time normal `split(',')` function should do and then take the first element (if there are no commas, there would only be one element) , and then split that by space again using `split(' ') and then get the last element using`[-1]` index.

Example -

```
>>> n = 'James Earl Carter, Jr.'.split(',')[0].split(' ')[-1]
>>> print(n)
Carter
>>> m = 'Ronald Wilson Reagan'.split(',')[0].split(' ')[-1]
>>> print(m)
Reagan
```

Comment: I think this can be better start..:). How to make lists please help

Comment: `['James Earl Carter, Jr.', ' 1977-1981', ' Democrat']` is a list, running `rsplit` or `split` function on strings, returns you a list. You can start learning about lists [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

Comment: This doesn't gives what OP is looking for!

Comment: This does answer the OP's question - `James Earl Carter, Jr. contains comma already so splitting is not working properly. How to do it ? Please help.`

Comment: OP wants `Carter` from name! and the years separately can you pls compare with your solution!!! I think the up voters didn't read any answer here!they just up vote based on habit!

Comment: OP can figure that out himself (If he cannot he can ask for more help here), it should be simple now, SO is not here to spoon-feed the complete code to people, we `help` them get their problems solved and from what I read , OP's ask was that he was having problem with the `Carter` row (complete string including year and party) and we wanted to know how splitting can work properly for that

Comment: Indeed, So is not a code writing service but this OP had an attempt for figure the problem out and your solution is not incorrect but it doesn't give a right hint because based on what OP wants first he/she is looking for columns then wants to separate the dates also if he/she wants to apply your solution on longer lists it would be very inefficient (you can imagine how it could be done with your solution) , and this answer would be remains for ever and a lot of people may used it. pleas always give a general and efficient answer!

Comment: Based on what OP asked, I gave him a simple answer, (also since you are adamant, i added a hint on how to get out `Carter` or `Reagan` , etc) . But if you have better answers ,you can post them, if they are really good, they would get the upvotes they deserve , why can't simple answers work for anyone, if they are really interested in efficiency, once they got an answer, they themselves would look for better efficient ones (Not everyone needs to be efficient everytime).

Comment: In my opinion Anand s. Kumar gave a very good answer, describing how to solve the most difficult part for the OP (it seems he was not aware of method `rsplit`). The OP can figure out by himself how to write the complete program.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` function and a [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex:

```
>>> s="""James Earl Carter, Jr., 1977-1981, Democrat
... Ronald Wilson Reagan, 1981-1989, Republican
... George Herbert Walker Bush, 1989-1993, Republican"""
>>> 
>>> list(zip(*[re.findall(r'\w+(?=[,-]|$)',i) for i in s.split('\n')]))
[('Carter', 'Reagan', 'Bush'), 
 ('1977', '1981', '1989'), 
 ('1981', '1989', '1993'), 
 ('Democrat', 'Republican', 'Republican')]
```

The following regular expression :

```
r'\w+(?=[,-]|$)'
```

will find any combinations of word characters that precede by `,` or `-` or comes at the end of string.

If you are dealing with longer lists I suggest to use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), that is more appropriate for such problems and also its good when your lists hasn't same columns number.It also accepts a `fillvalue` argument for fill the missing columns :

```
>>> s="""James Earl Carter, Jr., 1977-1981, Democrat,anothername,12222 
... Ronald Wilson Reagan, 1981-1989, Republican,33453
... George Herbert Walker Bush, 1989-1993, Republican"""

>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> list(zip_longest(*[re.findall(r'\w+(?=[,-]|$)',i) for i in s.split('\n')],fillvalue='**'))
[('Carter', 'Reagan', 'Bush'), 
 ('1977', '1981', '1989'), 
 ('1981', '1989', '1993'), 
 ('Democrat', 'Republican', 'Republican'), 
 ('anothername', '33453', '**')]
>>>
```

Note that in both cases if you want to iterate over the result of `izip_longest` or `zip` you don't need to call `list`.It's just for demonstrating the result!

Comment: Sorry, see edited post. I want ['Carter' , 'Reagan' , 'Bush']

Comment: Also what about other lists ?

Comment: This doesn't give them the output they're looking for at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use `re`

```
# Assume: s = 'James Earl Carter, Jr., 1977-1981, Democrat'
reg = re.compile('(\w+\s+)*(?P<name>\w+),\D*(?P<startyear>\d+)-(?P<endyear>\d+),\s*(?P<party>\w+)')
m = reg.search(s)
Name.append(m.group('name'))
StartYears.append(m.group('startyear'))
EndYears.append(m.group('endyear'))
Party.append(m.group('party'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this purpose. Considering that you want to avoid comma in between names I have used years to split the string first then process first part as name then second part as party.

```
search_string = """James Earl Carter, Jr., 1977-1981, Democrat
Ronald Wilson Reagan, 1981-1989, Republican
George Herbert Walker Bush, 1989-1993, Republican"""

import re
Name=[]
StartYears=[]
EndYears=[]
Party=[]
year = re.compile("[\d]{4}-[\d]{4}")
for i in search_string.split("\n"):
    split_string =  year.search(i).group(0)
    l = i.split(split_string)[0].split(",")[0].split()
    Name.append(l[-1])
    StartYears.append(split_string.split("-")[0])
    EndYears.append(split_string.split("-")[1])
    Party.append(i.split(split_string)[1].split(",")[1].strip())

print Name
print StartYears
print EndYears
print Party
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = []
start_years = []
end_years = []
party = []

for line in lines.split('\n'):
    fields = line.split(',')

    name.append(fields[:-2][0].split(' ')[-1])
    dates = fields[-2].replace(' ', '').split('-')
    start_years.append(dates[0])
    end_years.append(dates[1])
    party.append(fields[-1].replace(' ', ''))

print name
print start_years
print end_years
print party
```

#### the output

http://testedanswers.com/questions/-JsQv9KYv6vwJrj23Ost